# how to use EnumSystemLocales function and EnumLocalesProc callback function in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

```
int calculate (int a , int b)
{
return a+b;
}
int main ()
{
return 0 ;
}
```

as you know EnumSystemLocales and EnumLocalesProc are two API for callback any function . I want to use these API but there is no any example in msdn or anywhere . here I want to callback the calculate function using these API .

Comment: What has the question to do with you code???

Comment: @JochenKalmbach I want an example!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to use "[EnumSystemLocales](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317828)":

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL CALLBACK MyLocaleEnumProc(LPTSTR szLocaleString)
{
  _tprintf(_T("%s\r\n"), szLocaleString);
  return TRUE;
}

int _tmain()
{
  EnumSystemLocales(&MyLocaleEnumProc, LCID_INSTALLED);
  return 0;
}
```

If you just want to have a list of locales, you can do the following:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef std::vector<std::basic_string<TCHAR>> tLocales;
std::vector<std::basic_string<TCHAR>> g_locales;

BOOL CALLBACK MyLocaleEnumProc(LPTSTR szLocaleString)
{
  g_locales.push_back(szLocaleString);
  return TRUE;
}
int _tmain()
{
  // Get all locales
  EnumSystemLocales(&MyLocaleEnumProc, LCID_INSTALLED);

  // Print out all locales
  for(tLocales::const_iterator i=g_locales.begin(); i != g_locales.end(); i++)
  {
    _tprintf(_T("Locale: %s\r\n"), i->c_str());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: there is problem here , when I want run your code the MyLocaleEnumProc is called a lot (in screen print a text many time ) . I want the MyLocaleEnumProc only called one time !

Comment: What sense makes it to call a function which should return ALL installed locales in the callback, and you only want the first locale?